# How to compare smalldatetime in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, smalldatetime

I'm writing stored procedure to compare dates but it's not working properly.  How can I make it so it compares only the dates but not the time?  What I'm trying to do is compare the times and if the Id is null than insert a new entry with the same name but new time.  I'm keeping multiple entries with same name but different test time.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UL_TestData]
(
@Name varchar(30),  
@Test_Time smalldatetime,   
@ID INT output
)
AS
Declare  @UpdateTime smalldatetime
SELECT @ID=ID FROM Info_User WHERE Name=@Name AND  UpdateTime= @Test_Time
IF(@ID IS NULL)
 BEGIN
INSERT INTO Info_User (Name, UpdateTime) VALUES (@Name, @UpdateTime)    
 END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would cast the dates to a plain date which makes this solution independent of implementation details

```
select @ID=ID 
  from info_user
 where Name = @Name
   and cast (UpdateTime as Date) = Cast(@TestTime as Date)
```

However, I would either add the date part of the `UpdateTime` as an additional (calculated) column or split the information into a date and a time part. This makes it much easier to query entries by the plain date.

As a rule of thumb: The type of columns (in general: the table layout) greatly depends on the type of query you usually run against your data.

Edit: As attila pointed out, the `date` datatype only exists in version 2008 and up

Comment: I want to point out date only become a valid type in ms sql server 2008.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will add this to my solution.

Answer (score 1):

there are a lot of solutions to this depending on what type of DBMS, however here is one:

```
SELECT @ID=ID FROM Info_User WHERE Name=@Name AND floor(cast(@UpdateTime as float))= floor(cast(@Test_Time as float))
```

this works because smalldatetime's date is stored a whole numbers, where the time is stored as decimals.

Comment: Can I use this to also compare which date is the last updated one? Meaning if 1/12/2014 is greater than 3/12/2013 than do not update the time?

Comment: Yes.  But you do not need to convert the small datetime to compare the values.